# .js file being blocked by all browsers

Tags: javascript, security, multiple-browsers

I am working my way through the following [tutorial](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/password-strength-verification-with-jquery/) and everything works great except for one significant detail:  When I test the page in any browser I get a warning message that content unsecure content is being blocked.  Once I acknowledge the warning and choose "allow blocked content" or a similar option, it works just fine.  Obviously this will be problematic if left as is and put into production.

This is the body of the .js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type=password]')
        .keyup(function () {
            // keyup code here
        })
        .focus(function () {
            $('#pswd_info')
                .show();
        })
        .blur(function () {
            $('#pswd_info')
                .hide();
        });
});
```

My question is how do I implement the code so it does not throw warnings and is automatically blocked by browsers?

I look forward to your insights and expertise.

Comment: Are you loading a script via HTTP into a HTTPS site? It hardly has to do with the content of the script file (unless your antivirus program intercepts it and check it for malicious things, which would explain the cross-browser message appearance)

Comment: It is being called on a HTTPS site.  I changed the call to  src="https://mysite.com/pwd_script.js" (this editor is truncating it, but I put the entire path with https://)  from  src="pwd_script.js"  and still no dice.

Comment: Could the issue be that the page is https and it makes a call to "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" which is not https?  If so, how do you work around that?

Comment: That as well - all ressources on a secure site need to be loaded with a secure connection otherwise the page is considered tainted. Just load [https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js)

Comment: That did it, Bergi.  Thanks for leading me there!

Answer (score 2):

> I get a warning message that content unsecure content is being blocked.

You seem to be on a secure (HTTPS) site and loading your scripts via HTTP. All ressources  need to be loaded with a secure connection otherwise the page would be corrupted.